# Find overlapping segments in multiple columns

Tags: r, overlap

I have following data set and would like to get in a separate column the number of overlapping labels (`n.overlaps`), the name of the overlapping labels (`overlap.labels`) and also the duration of the overlap (`overlap.duration`).

This is my data set:

```
label   begin   end
======================
lower   9.03    12.41
lower   28.773  29.975
lower   33.895  35.992
lower   46.814  48.854
lower   58.51   61.51
lower   62.971  63.491
upper   28.132  30.432
upper   46.716  50.82
upper   58.536  61.482
upper   29.975  33.895
upper   53.376  54.08
upper   10.358  11.958
upper   30.532  46.716
upper   51.633  58.536
head    9.918   14.818
head    29.823  30.623
head    58.802  61.404
head    61.404  63.562
```

The table, I would like to get would be this one:

```
lower.begin    lower.end    upper.begin     upper.end   head.begin  head.end    n.overlaps  overlap.labels       overlap.duration
9.03           12.41         10.358         11.958        9.918      14.418         3        lower|upper|head         1.6
28.773         29.975        28.132         30.432        29.823     30.623         3        lower|upper|head         0.152
33.895         35.992        30.532         46.716         -            -           2        lower|upper              2.097
...
```

This is the visual representation of the table:

[image]

## Data

```
structure(list(label = c("lower", "lower", "lower", "lower", 
"lower", "lower", "upper", "upper", "upper", "upper", "upper", 
"upper", "upper", "upper", "head", "head", "head", "head"
), begin = c(9.03, 28.773, 33.895, 46.814, 58.51, 62.971, 28.132, 
46.716, 58.536, 29.975, 53.376, 10.358, 30.532, 51.633, 9.918, 
29.823, 58.802, 61.404), end = c(12.41, 29.975, 35.992, 48.854, 
61.51, 63.491, 30.432, 50.82, 61.482, 33.895, 54.08, 11.958, 
46.716, 58.536, 14.818, 30.623, 61.404, 63.562)), .Names = c("label", 
"begin", "end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is really a comment but it comes with a picture.

Your desired output is deeply unclear. Specifically, it appears as if there are three groups of overlap for your example data,colored cyan, light green and plum:

[image]

It's not even clear what you want once we agree that these are the three overlap regions.

## Code for Plot

```
library(data.table); setDT(x)
cols<-c(lower="black",upper="blue",middle="red")
ys<-c(lower=1.8,upper=2.2,middle=2)
par(mar=c(2.1,4.1,4.1,1.1))
x[,{plot(1,type="n",xlim=range(onset,offset),
        ylim=c(1.7,2.3),yaxt="n",ylab="",xlab="",
        main="Depiction of Intervals")
  axis(side=2,at=ys[unique(label)],
       labels=unique(label),las=1)}]
rect(x[order(onset)][1,onset],1.7,
     x[order(offset)][3,offset],2.3,col="cyan")
rect(x[order(onset)][4,onset],1.7,
     x[order(offset)][11,offset],2.3,col="lightgreen")
rect(x[order(onset)][12,onset],1.7,
     x[order(offset)][18,offset],2.3,col="plum")
for (lbs in x[,unique(label)]){
  x[label==lbs,
    arrows(onset,ys[label],offset,ys[label],lwd=3,
           code=3,angle=90,length=.07,col=cols[label])]
}
```

Comment: I added the correct graphical representation of the table. It might be useful to understand the table, I would like to have.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start. When I get more time I will add the last three columns. It looks complicated, but I'm using `lubridate` to turn the durations into time intervals. There's a function called `new_interval` that creates them, and one called `int_overlaps` that tests for overlaps.

**Update**

The code is complete. Check back if it helps or not.

```
library(lubridate)

starts <- as.POSIXct(df$begin, origin=Sys.time())
ends <- as.POSIXct(df$end, origin=Sys.time())

spans <- new_interval(starts, ends)
s <- split(spans, df$label)
d <- split(df, df$label)

overlap <- function(x1, x2) {

  out <- sapply(1:length(s[[x1]]), function(x) {
    which(int_overlaps(s[[x1]][x], s[[x2]]))}
    )

    mat_lst <- lapply(out, function(x) {
      matrix(c(d[[x2]]$begin[x],d[[x2]]$end[x]),ncol=2)}
      )

    mat_lst[lengths(mat_lst) == 0L] <- list(matrix(NA, ncol=2))
    mat_lst

}

lh <- overlap("lower", "head")
lu <- overlap("lower", "upper")
matches <- suppressWarnings(lapply(1:nrow(d$lower), function(x) {
  cbind(d$lower[x,2:3], lu[[x]], lh[[x]])}
))
new_df <- `names<-`(do.call(rbind, matches), c("lower.begin", "lower.end", "upper.begin", "upper.end", "head.begin", "head.end"))
rownames(new_df) <- NULL

#n.overlaps
count <- colSums(apply(new_df, 1, function(x) !is.na(x)))/2
new_df$n.overlaps <- ave(count, new_df$lower.begin, FUN=function(x) x+length(x)-1)

#overlap.labels
new_df$overlap.labels <- apply(new_df[1:6], 1, function(x) 
  paste(unique(gsub("\\..*", "", names(which(!is.na(x))))), collapse="|"))


#overlap.duration
first <- pmin(new_df$lower.end, new_df$upper.end)-new_df$upper.begin
second <- pmin(new_df$lower.end, new_df$head.end)-new_df$head.begin
overlap <- ifelse(is.na(first+second), ifelse(is.na(first), second, first), first+second)
new_df$overlap.duration <- ave(overlap, new_df$lower.begin, FUN=sum)
new_df
#   lower.begin lower.end upper.begin upper.end head.begin head.end n.overlaps
# 1       9.030    12.410      10.358    11.958      9.918   14.818          3
# 2      28.773    29.975      28.132    30.432     29.823   30.623          4
# 3      28.773    29.975      29.975    33.895     29.823   30.623          4
# 4      33.895    35.992      29.975    33.895         NA       NA          3
# 5      33.895    35.992      30.532    46.716         NA       NA          3
# 6      46.814    48.854      46.716    50.820         NA       NA          2
# 7      58.510    61.510      58.536    61.482     58.802   61.404          4
# 8      58.510    61.510      51.633    58.536     61.404   63.562          4
# 9      62.971    63.491          NA        NA     61.404   63.562          2
#     overlap.labels overlap.duration
# 1 lower|upper|head            4.092
# 2 lower|upper|head            2.147
# 3 lower|upper|head            2.147
# 4      lower|upper            9.380
# 5      lower|upper            9.380
# 6      lower|upper            2.138
# 7 lower|upper|head           12.557
# 8 lower|upper|head           12.557
# 9       lower|head            2.087
```

**Update #2**

I spruced up the `matches` function. It should be ready for more variety. Replace it in the old script.

```
matches <- suppressWarnings(lapply(1:nrow(d$lower), function(x) {
  max.len <- max(length(c(length(lu[[x]]), length(lh[[x]]))))
  xu <- lu[[x]]
  xh <- lh[[x]]
  dim(xu) <- dim(xh) <- NULL
  length(xu) <- length(xh) <- max.len
  umat <- matrix(xu, byrow=T, ncol=2)
  hmat <- matrix(xh, byrow=T, ncol=2)
  cbind(d$lower[x,2:3], umat, hmat)}
))
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(label = c("lower", "lower", "lower", "lower", 
"lower", "lower", "upper", "upper", "upper", "upper", "upper", 
"upper", "upper", "upper", "head", "head", "head", "head"
), begin = c(9.03, 28.773, 33.895, 46.814, 58.51, 62.971, 28.132, 
46.716, 58.536, 29.975, 53.376, 10.358, 30.532, 51.633, 9.918, 
29.823, 58.802, 61.404), end = c(12.41, 29.975, 35.992, 48.854, 
61.51, 63.491, 30.432, 50.82, 61.482, 33.895, 54.08, 11.958, 
46.716, 58.536, 14.818, 30.623, 61.404, 63.562)), .Names = c("label", 
"begin", "end"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

Comment: It looks complicated but it's a very good start. This is what I was looking for. Hope you find time to finish the missing three columns. Thank you already for this part.

Comment: Hey Pierre! Is there any chance that you'll find time for finishing the code in next couple of days? That would be cool.

Comment: You have an old version of R. Install 3.2.2. It has many new functions and bug fixes.

Comment: If that doesn't work. replace `mat_lst[lengths(mat_lst) == 0L]` with `mat_lst[unlist(lapply(mat_lst, length)) == 0L]`

Comment: There is a typo in  `mat_lst[lengths(mat_lst) == 0L] <- list(matrix(NA, ncol=2))` it should be `length`. I cannot run `matches <- suppressWarnings(lapply(1:nrow(d$lower), function(x) {
  cbind(d$lower[x,2:3], lu[[x]], lh[[x]])}
))`. I get an error message: `Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : The arguments have a different numer of raws: 1, 2, 3...` Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: That's not a typo. Try it on the example you gave to test. Your data has a different structure than the example you provided. Not only are there multiple matches to 'lower', there are more layers of matches within each group. I will have to beef up the code to account for the other possibilities. You can use Arun's approach or give me time to look at it.

Comment: Your code works on the provided example from the question. I used your code to my actual data (much larger than 18 rows) and I wanted to report on it to. I wasn't aware, it's going to create a mess. I very much appreciate your help and don't wanna stress anyone.

Comment: The code works now perfectly. Thank you! One last question. If I would like to add a 4th label category, e.g. `gaze`, to the already existing one (`head`,`upper`,`lower`), what would I have to change in the code?Is it something simple that I can do?  I'm asking that now, so that I don't have to bother anyone in the future.

Comment: I tried to change those places. Would you mind having look at it? Please see the Update #3 with the extended data (I added only 4 examples of `gaze` for fun). I wasn't sure how to adjust the last row with `overlap`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt using `foverlaps` from `data.table`:

```
subset_dat <- function(x, .label) {
  ans = x[label == .label]
  setnames(ans, paste(.label, names(ans), sep="_"))
}
setkey(setDT(dat), begin, end))
olaps1 = foverlaps(subset_dat(dat, "head"), subset_dat(dat, "lower"), type="any")
olaps2 = foverlaps(subset_dat(dat, "upper"), subset_dat(dat, "lower"), type="any")
ans  = merge(olaps1, olaps2, by=names(olaps1)[1:3], all=TRUE)

ans[, olap.labels := paste(lower_label, head_label, upper_label, sep="|")]
ans[, olap.labels := gsub("\\|NA|NA\\|", "", olap.labels)]
ans[, c("lower_label", "head_label", "upper_label") := NULL]
ans[, olap.count := sapply(gregexpr("\\|", olap.labels), function(x) sum(x != -1L)+1L)]
ans[, olap.interval := abs(pmax(lower_begin, head_begin, upper_begin, na.rm=TRUE) - 
                           pmin(lower_end, head_end, upper_end, na.rm=TRUE))]

#     lower_begin lower_end head_begin head_end upper_begin upper_end      olap.labels olap.count olap.interval
#  1:          NA        NA         NA       NA      53.376    54.080            upper          1         0.704
#  2:       9.030    12.410      9.918   14.818      10.358    11.958 lower|head|upper          3         1.600
#  3:      28.773    29.975     29.823   30.623      28.132    30.432 lower|head|upper          3         0.152
#  4:      28.773    29.975     29.823   30.623      29.975    33.895 lower|head|upper          3         0.000
#  5:      33.895    35.992         NA       NA      29.975    33.895      lower|upper          2         0.000
#  6:      33.895    35.992         NA       NA      30.532    46.716      lower|upper          2         2.097
#  7:      46.814    48.854         NA       NA      46.716    50.820      lower|upper          2         2.040
#  8:      58.510    61.510     58.802   61.404      51.633    58.536 lower|head|upper          3         0.266
#  9:      58.510    61.510     58.802   61.404      58.536    61.482 lower|head|upper          3         2.602
# 10:      58.510    61.510     61.404   63.562      51.633    58.536 lower|head|upper          3         2.868
# 11:      58.510    61.510     61.404   63.562      58.536    61.482 lower|head|upper          3         0.078
# 12:      62.971    63.491     61.404   63.562          NA        NA       lower|head          2         0.520
```

Comment: I tried to replicate your code on the provided data set and am failing in running the `setDT(dat, key=c("begin", "end"))`.I'm getting error message that the `key` argument is unused. I installed packages `data.table` and `overlaps` in advance. I don't know where am I failing.

Comment: @user5264244, `setDT()` can set keys in the current devel version. Fixed with call to `setkey()`. Should work now.